# Wrap text around image

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, vsto, word-2010

I have the following which works fine:

```
sbMainText.Append("Lor...

sbMainText.Append("Lor...

sbMainText.Append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium ultricies lorem eu cursus. Curabitur sit amet arcu elit. Sed.");
bmkRange = AppendToRange(bmkRange, sbMainText.ToString(), out r);
r.Font.Bold = 0;
r.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = 0;
r.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\\Capture1.PNG");
sbMainText.Clear();

sbMainText.Append("Lor...

sbMainText.Append("Lor...
```

This just gives me a paragraph and right above the paragraph I get the image.  It's a word document project created with visual studio.  However, I want to text wrap the text around the image, instead of having the image above the text.  How do I do that?

Comment: consider using http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html#.U5nN6fRDtho?

Comment: or have a look at this http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/07/13/create-a-word-document-containing-a-picture-that-makes-text-to-flow-around-it-in-c.aspx